# Binomial Random Variable in Python

Tags: python, stat

I'm attempting to solve the below question using just one line of code:

'Suppose you take a multiple choice test with 10 questions, and each question has 5 answer choices (a,b,c,d,e), what is the probability you get exactly 4 questions correct just by guessing?'

I know the answer is 0.08808 or around 9%.

I'm trying to use the below line to reflect this answer as well

```
import numpy as np
#number of trials = 10
#number of answers for each question = 5
#probability of answering one correctly = 1/5 or 0.2
# == 1 because 1/0 will indicate correct or incorrect

sum(np.random.binomial(5, 0.2, 10) == 1)/10.

0.2
```

Can someone shed some light on how to get 0.08808 instead of 0.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code for getting the probability you seek:

```
import math

def combinations_of_n_choose_m(n, m):
    return math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(n - m)/math.factorial(m)

def probability_of_correct_trials(trials, correct, prob):
    return combinations_of_n_choose_m(trials, correct) * prob**correct * (1-prob)**(trials-correct)

print(probability_of_correct_trials(10, 4, .2))
```

Or in one line:

```
r = math.factorial(10)/math.factorial(10 - 4)/math.factorial(4) * prob**4 * (1-prob)**(10-4)
print(r)
```

Result:

```
0.08808038400000005
```

I put this together using two references: https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/binomial-probability and https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/combinations.html

I see from @PatrickLaub's answer where you were trying to go.  It seems that you wanted to get to your answer empirically...by running trials to see what happens.  You should have been testing for `4`, and your first parameter to the `binomial` function wasn't right, but you were on the right track.  The big issue with your code though is that to get an answer with any precision, you need to run millions of trials.  You were running just 10.  So Patrick does give you the answer you want if you're looking for a single-line empirically computing expression:

```
r = np.mean(rnd.binomial(10, .2, 10**6) == 4)
print(r)
```

My last run of this gave:

```
0.08828
```

That's quite clever.  If that's what you wanted, please give Patrick the credit for it. I just wanted to put it here to complete my answer.

Comment: For the record, binomial coefficients are available in the `math` library as `math.comb` since Python 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

The Monte Carlo way to approximate this probability is to get Python to generate a huge number of exams (say, a million), where each exam has n=10 questions and p=1/5 chance of guessing the correct answer. Then you look at the simulated exam results & find the fraction which happened to get 4 correct answer out of the total number of simulated exams.

```
import numpy.random as rnd 

n = 10; p = 1/5
numTrials = 10**6
numTimesFourCorrect = 0

for trial in range(numTrials):
    numAnswersCorrect = rnd.binomial(n, p)
    if numAnswersCorrect == 4:
        numTimesFourCorrect += 1

print(numTimesFourCorrect / numTrials)
```

One run of this gave 0.088242 on my machine (it's different each time), so pretty close to what you are expecting. The main problem with your original code, is that `np.random.binomial(n, p, numTrials)` will give you `numTrials` outcomes which are numbers between 0 and n; so something like `np.mean(rnd.binomial(n, p, numTrials) == 4)` is the vectorised way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on the help available at [numpy.random.binomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html?highlight=binomial#numpy.random.binomial)

```
In [20]: NumberOfTrials = 10
    ...: ProbOfSuccess = 0.2
    ...: TotalTrials = 1000000
    ...: 
    ...: sum(np.random.binomial(NumberOfTrials , ProbOfSuccess, TotalTrials)==4)/TotalTrials
Out[20]: 0.08818
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add that it is possible to get the exact analytical solution with `sympy` as follows:

```
from sympy import stats, Eq
import fractions

# 10 questions with probability of success given by 1/5
X = stats.Binomial('X', 10, fractions.Fraction(1, 5))
P = stats.Probability(Eq(X, 4)).evaluate_integral()
# 172032/1953125 (exact answer)
approx = 172032/1953125
# 0.088080384
```